# Thymeleaf: Update Table on Form Submit

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have a view in which I have a Form to create a new Exercise object, and a table to display all exercises. Now I want that the table automatically refreshes with the newly created exercise. Currently it displays the table as empty, until I manually go to `localhost:8080/exercise` again.

Here's my controller:

```
@Controller
public class ExerciseController {

    @Autowired
    private ExerciseService exerciseService;

    @Autowired
    private ModelMapper modelMapper;

    @GetMapping("/exercise")
    public String exerciseView(final Model model) {

        List<Exercise> exerciseList = exerciseService.getAllExercises();

        model.addAttribute("exerciseDTO", new ExerciseDTO());
        model.addAttribute("title", "Create an Exercise");
        model.addAttribute("exercises", exerciseList);
        return "exercise";
    }

    @PostMapping("/exercise")
    public String createExercise(@ModelAttribute final ExerciseDTO exerciseDto) {

        final Exercise exercise = this.modelMapper.map(exerciseDto, Exercise.class);

        this.exerciseService.createExercise(exercise);
        return "exercise";
    }
}
```

And my thymeleaf template:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="template :: head"></head>
<body>
    <header th:replace="template :: navbar"></header>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form action="#" th:action="@{/exercise}" th:object="${exerciseDTO}" method="post">
        <p>Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{name}" /></p>
        <p>Description: <input type="text" th:field="*{description}" /></p>
        <p>Exercise type:
            <select th:field="*{type}" id="typeSelector">
                <option th:each="type : ${T(com.nsterdt.routinierbackend.data.enums.ExerciseType).values()}"
                th:value="${type}" th:text="${type.displayName}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p id="bpmRow">BPM: <input type="number" th:field="*{bpm}" id="bpmInput" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>

    <br>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>BPM</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="exercise : ${exercises}">
            <td th:text="${exercise.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${exercise.description}"></td>
            <td th:text="${exercise.type}"></td>
            <td th:text="${exercise.bpm}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Now I thought the `createExercise` method returning "exercise" would call the `exerciseView` method and thus calling `exerciseService.getAllExercises()`. Is there a way to achieve this functionality? Or is there an even better way, without reloading the whole page?

Answer (score 1):

To serve up data without page refreshes you'd need a client side technology like Angular or React.  Or plain old javascript.  But you can't serve up new data to a page in spring mvc w/o page refreshes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'd rather not use a JS Framework, as I'm only trying to get learn plain JavaScript. Could you maybe give me a hint on how to solve something like that?

Comment: @marc, how can i get it to work with a page refresh. I am using thymeleaf with spring MVC. Currently trying to figure out how to implement  a search function to show search results

Comment: Simplest way would be to use the sql LIKE operator to fetch your results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use AJAX to send requests from a client side to a server side and receive an answer without refreshing the page.

Unfortunately I don't have enough time and I can't complete the code but you can do something like this:

```
function submitItems() {

    var contextPath = $("meta[name='ctx']").attr("content");

    var exerciseDto = {};
    exerciseDto.name = $("#name").val();
    exerciseDto.description = $("#description").val();
    exerciseDto.typeSelector = $("#typeSelector).val();
    exerciseDto.bpmInput = $("#bpmInput").val();

    $.ajax({
        dataType : "json",
        type : "post",
        url : contextPath + "/exercise",
        data : JSON.stringify(exerciseDto),
        cache : false,
        contentType : "application/json",
        beforeSend : function(xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader(header, token);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            //HERE YOU NEED ACTION TO UPDATE TABLE.
        },
        error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log('getJSON request failed! ' + textStatus);
        }
    });
}
```

and then your view must be like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:replace="template :: head"></head>
<body>
    <header th:replace="template :: navbar"></header>
    <h1>Form</h1>
    <form onsubmit="submitItems();return false;">
        <p>Name: <input id="name" type="text" /></p>
        <p>Description: <input id="description" type="text" /></p>
        <p>Exercise type:
            <select th:field="*{type}" id="typeSelector">
                <option th:each="type : ${T(com.nsterdt.routinierbackend.data.enums.ExerciseType).values()}"
                th:value="${type}" th:text="${type.displayName}">
                </option>
            </select>
        </p>
        <p id="bpmRow">BPM: <input type="number" id="bpmInput" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    </form>

    <br>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Description</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>BPM</th>
        </tr>
        <tr th:each="exercise : ${exercises}">
            <td th:text="${exercise.name}"></td>
            <td th:text="${exercise.description}"></td>
            <td th:text="${exercise.type}"></td>
            <td th:text="${exercise.bpm}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Bear in mind that you need to create an JS action that will update the table. There are quite a few ways of doing that (you can push new data to the Datatable or add new content using JS functions).

I hope this will help you understand a bit more how the AJAX works.

PS. You will have to update your controller as well to return the results, in your instance will be

```
@PostMapping("/exercise")
    public createExerciseDomainTYPEHERE createExercise(@RequestBody final ExerciseDTO exerciseDto) {

        final Exercise exercise = this.modelMapper.map(exerciseDto, Exercise.class);

        //this.exerciseService.createExercise(exercise);
        //return "exercise";
        return this.exerciseService.createExercise(exercise);
    }
```

You will have to change this line

> public createExerciseDomainTYPEHERE createExercise(@RequestBody final ExerciseDTO exerciseDto) {

to your createExercise Domain Type.

Comment: I don't think the `$(..)` and `$.` syntax is part of JavaScript. How would I do it with plain JavaScript?